# NoMethodError - undefined method - Trying to register new products - rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build a screen to register new products, but i keep getting this error:
[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkeTH.png)

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    post "despensa", to:"despensa#create"
    get "despensa/new", to: "despensa#new"
    root to: "despensa#index"
end
```

despensa_controller.rb:

```
class DespensaController < ApplicationController
    
    def index
        @produtos = Produto.order :nome
        @produto_menor_quantidade = Produto.order(:quantidade).limit 1    
    end

    def create
       produto = params.require(:produto).permit(:nome, :quantidade, :unidade_de_medida)
       Produto.create produto
    end
end
```

new:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <%= form_for Produto.new do |form|%>
            Nome <input type="text" name="nome"><br/>
            Quantidade<input type="number" step="0.01" name="quantidade"><br/>
            Unidade de medida <input type="text" name="unidade_de_medida"><br/>
            
            <button type="submit">Adicionar produto</button>
        <% end %>
    </body>
</html>
```

I really don't know what is causing it. It was suppose to open a form page to register the new products. please help

Comment: You don't specify a path for your form, so it tries to guess from your class name. Just use `form_for(Produto.new, url: despensas_path)` (you declare your routes weirdly, so I'm not sure how your create route is actually named, use `rails routes` to find out)

Comment: Thank u very much, it solved my problem. I'm following a course so I'm not sure how i supposed to declare the routes, but i'm going to look for that. Thank u